# Why does the "list index out of range" error only show up when I input 10?

Tags: python

I understand that my index cannot be bigger than 8 in this instance, so inputting 10 (consequently xInput would equal 9) gives list index out of range. But any number bigger than 10 seems to work perfectly fine.

I tried

```py
while xInput < 0 or xInput >= 9 or 'o' == board[xInput] or 'x' == board[xInput]:
```

and it does work correctly. But I can't seem to understand why this works while my other one doesn't.

This is my original code

```py
board = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
xInput = 90
oInput = 90
while xInput < 0 or xInput > 9 or 'o' == board[xInput] or 'x'==board[xInput]:
        xInput = int(input("x: ")) - 1
board[xInput] = 'x'
```

Comment: If `xInput > 9` is `True` then the rest is not evaluated at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `or` conditions to evaluate.

When any of the conditions is true, the rest is not evaluated at all.

```
example: A or B or C, where A/B/C could be some expression.

The boolean value of this depends on whether any of A/B/C is true.
```

In case you need to control more tightly, you could try using `and` or `xor` conditions

Answer (score 0):

For any `xInput` greater than 9, you remain trapped in the `while` loop because `xInput > 9` is one of the conditions in the loop.

The line of code which triggers the IndexError:

```py
board[xInput] = 'x'
```

Never gets reached

Answer (score 0):

The reason inputting 10 (so `xInput = 9`) throws an exception is because your `board` list is only a length of 9. In your `while` loop, it will exit if `xInput == 9` because you have it set to loop only if `xInput` is *less than* 9.

So if `xInput` is 9, then it tries to evaluate `board[9]`, which doesn't exist, since lists are indexed starting at 0 and not 1. Thus,

```
board[0] == 1
board[1] == 2
...
board[8] == 9
board[9] == ???
```

The while loop you mentioned first is correct, because there, you have the loop condition `xInput <= 9`, instead of `xInput < 9`, so it will only exit the loop if `xInput == 8`, which will evaluate correctly.